# Adding data to nested lists in Python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am trying to build a nested list for my website's gallery. I am pulling data from a database and inserting it into the list, and then my gallery page adds elements from the list to my webpage.

**My list is:**

```py
gallery = [[], [[]]]
```

For every element in `gallery[0]`, which holds all the years, there is a corresponding list in `gallery[1]`, and each list holds lists that store all the photo names, an event, a date, etc. The issue that I am having is that as I loop through my list, every sublist in `gallery[1]` has the same photo names in it, even though the dateof each sublist is unique.

**The loop adding the photos:**

```py
images = db.session.query(Gallery.image_file_th, Gallery.image_file_fl, Gallery.date).order_by(Gallery.image_order)
    for y in gallery[0]: # LOOP THROUGH THE YEARS
        for x in range(len(gallery[1])):
            for w in range(len(gallery[1][x])): # LOOP THROUGH LIST CORRESPONDING TO YEARS
                for pic in images: # LOOP THROUGH EACH IMAGE NAME PULLED FROM THE DATABASE
                    if str(pic.date) == str(gallery[1][x][w][0]):
                        gallery[1][x][w][2].append(pic.image_file_fl)
                        gallery[1][x][w][3].append(pic.image_file_th)
                    else:
                        pass
```

I am appending the photos to lists that are contained in the sublists at index 2 and 3.

**Sample gallery list:**

```py
gallery = [[2019], [[
        [date_of_event, event_name, [list_of_thumbnails], [list_of_photos]]
    ]]]
```

*Why are the same photos appearing in both sublists?* I will be happy to supply more information if it is requested.

Comment: *"For every element in ... there is a corresponding list in ..."*  This is a good indicator that you should be using a `dict` at the top level instead of a `list`.

Comment: i thought of using a dictionary, but is seemed easiest for me to loop through a list. I am using Flask. Is there an easy way to loop through a dictionary and add the data to a webpage?

Comment: using a dict is definitely easier and the performance would be better too. Consider reforming your `galleries` into a dict with meaningful keys like `year`, `date`, `name`, etc. Your dictionary can look like `{'year1': {'file_fl': 'file_th'}}` or something like that. The retrieval will be a lot faster as it's O(1) instead of O(n)

Comment: looping through dict is the same as looping through list with a for loop. In python, you will need to call `dict_name.items()` or `dict_name.itertiems()` if you use py2. You will need to unpack the dictionary into keys and values so the for loop can look something like `for k,v in dict_name.items(): # do something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @0x5453 and @JChao for the suggestion to use a dictionary rather than nested lists.

The issue with the for loop is that I had declared each list with the same variable:

```py
gallery[key_year].append(
                    {
                        'date': y.date,
                        'title': y.event,
                        'fulls': fulls, # declared as fulls = []
                        'thumbs': thumbs, # declared as thumbs = []
                        'date_parsed': y.date.strftime('%A, %b %-d'),
                        'id': ide
                    }
                )
```

This caused the issue described in the question.

**The solution:**

```py
gallery[key_year].append(
                    {
                        'date': y.date,
                        'title': y.event,
                        'fulls': [],
                        'thumbs': [],
                        'date_parsed': y.date.strftime('%A, %b %-d'),
                        'id': ide
                    }
                )
```